# Specifying an attribute in a generic React component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a generic React select component to show a list of options labeled as whatever is passed to the component. My issue is that I want to be able to specify which attribute to use when printing the records which will not always be the same. For instance, if I pass an array of authors, I would use the full_name attribute to populate the list; however, if I wanted to print a list of books, I would want to use title.

I have an options function that I call to populate the select which looks like this:

```
options = () => {
  return this.props.collection.map(o => {
    return ( 
      <option key={o.id} value={o.id}>/*DISPLAY METHOD HERE*/</option>
    )
  })
}
```

Basically I want to be able to pass in a prop to the component specifying the attribute I want to use (full_name, title, etc) and call that on o (o.full_name, o.title, ...) in the return call. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I fully understood your question but if you try to access an arbitrary method of an object it is the same in JS as accessing an arbitrary attribute.

So you could like with attributes just access the method by string.
For example for your title:

```html
    const Foo = (o, title) => {
      return o[title]();
    }

    Foo({ Fantastic: () => console.log('Four'), }, 'Fantastic');
```

"o[title]" would get you the method and "()" invoke it

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear, I was having trouble putting my question into words. I cannot use a string because I don't know what the method is going to be passed in. I need to do something like o[this.props.displayMethod] where displayMethod is passed in to the component.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const SelectPicker = ({ data }) => (
    <select>
      {Object.keys(data).map(key => (
        <option value={key}>{data[key]}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );

function App() {
  var obj = {
    userOne: "John Doe",
    userTwo: "John Smith"
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SelectPicker data={obj} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

You might look for something like this?

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still doesn't get me to where I can specify an attribute of the collection's objects to display. The collection is basically json with many objects such as {"books": [{"id": 1, "author_id": 5, "title":"Bar"}, {"id": 2, "author_id": 5, "title":"Foo"}, {"id": 3, "author_id": 1, "title":"Blah"},... ]}. But I would also want to be able to pass other collections too. For example a json of authors with the attributes of fullName, dateOfBirth, homeTown, etc. In the first case I would specify I want to use the title; in the later I would indicate fullName